# JPA Equivalent of Oracle TopLink's addBatchReadAttribute

Tags: jpa, batch-file, toplink

We're using JPA, and when a collection of objects returns from a query, a separate query is executed for each "child" object related through a foreign key.

For example, in our Authorization entity class, we have the following Client object mapped:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "clientId", referencedColumnName = "clientId")
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotNull(groups = Default.class)
private Client client;
```

When 10 Authorizations are returned, 10 Client queries are executed.  In TopLink, I was able to bring this number to one with the ReadAllQuery class's addBatchReadAttribute() method.   According to the TopLink docs, "when any of the batched parts is accessed, the parts will all be read in a single query, this allows all of the data required for the parts to be read in a single query instead of (n) queries."

This worked perfectly, giving us a single query using an IN clause with 10 ids.

What I read about re: JPA pointed me toward a batch join or something like:

```
hints = {@QueryHint(name = "eclipselink.batch", value = "p.client"), ...
```

This strategy helps reduce the number of queries,

- but it also gave me more joins, possibly slowing things down (?) on
  some queries
- and it didn't seem to help as drastically as the TopLink call.

Is there a way to get the strategy that uses a single query with IN in the WHERE clause?

Thanks in advance.
Dave

Answer (score 1):

Internally the QueryHint "eclipselink.batch" is translated to addBatchAttribute() so the behaviour you see should be identical.  Does the JPQL you have created produce the same query as the native TopLink API?  It is possible you have Fetch's or additional joins in the JPQL?

Comment: No, it does not.  The hint I posted changes a number of the queries to use joins.   The TopLink addBatchReadAttribute(...) call turns:

SELECT * FROM Authorization

Comment: No the hint I posted above turns some queries into joins. The addBatchReadAttribute(...) TopLink method turns a block like this: SELECT ... FROM Authorization -- this returns 10 records, each referring to a different Client record SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId = 0 SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId = 1 ... SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId = 8 SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId = 9 into this block: SELECT ... FROM Authorization SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

Comment: No the hint I posted above turns some queries into joins. The addBatchReadAttribute(...) TopLink method turns a block like this: 

  SELECT ... FROM Authorization -- this returns 10 records, each referring to a different Client record 
  SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId = 0 
  SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId = 1 
  ... 
  SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId = 8 
  SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId = 9 

into this block: 
  
  SELECT ... FROM Authorization 
  SELECT ... FROM Client WHERE ClientId IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink supports several types of batch fetching.

See,
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html